# Stuck with UTF-8 using API in perl

Tags: perl

Kinda new to Perl. I am using Perl web API to get the data. The error is "application/xml; charset=UTF-8". I used 'use utf8' but doesn't seem to work. The line it gets stuck looks something like this

```
my @candidates = $c->bookmarks_for(start => 1, tag =>'pubmed');
```

Can you please help me.

Thank you,
Sammed

Comment: Ah, Perl, we meet again.

Comment: That looks like a content-type, not an error. What is the full error? What actually happens?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The

```
use utf8;
```

is only (and only) for one thing. When you will use in your source code utf8 characters. For example:

```
my $utf8str = "αΩ";
```

For any other thins, for example:

```
my $data = MyModule::get_some_data();
```

you should use

```
my $utf8data = Encode::decode_utf8($data);
```

In the case, when your get_some_data returning octets (bytes).

For example, when reading text files, you can tell perl utf8 conversion at IO level with,

```
open($fd, "<", $filename);
$fd->binmode(:utf8); #for marking data as utf8, or
$fd->binmode(:encoding(utf8)); #for marking *and* checking data for utf8 validity too.
```

Or you can use the open pragma for telling perl using utf8 as default at IO layer

```
use open(:std :utf8);
```

Here is no short answer. You *really* should read:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html

Perl is extremely strong in utf8 processing, but you must know, hot to use it properly - unfortunately, here is no shorter way as RTFM...

And note: here are differences in utf8 processing in perl <5.6, 5.6, 5.8, 5.12, 5.14...

Comment: +1 Great answer. It bugs me though, that in 2011 we're **still** jumping through these hoops. Recent Perl versions should have made UTF8 the default, and required this sort of thing to be done when one needs to support something else.

Comment: @Sherm, you’re being naïve: there is no magic bullet. If you think that’s such a good idea, just set your `PERL_UNICODE` envariable to `SAD` and see what breaks.

Comment: @Tom - I don't expect a magic bullet. It's good to have the old behavior, **as an option**. What I think is ridiculous is that the old behavior is still the default. It's 2011 - Unicode should be the default, and there should be a PERL_NO_UNICODE environment variable available for scripts that still can't deal with it.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley: nope.  lots and lots of perl programs out there use strings for arbitrary binary data.  And that is completely inconsistent with what you want.